# Use Linux to backup a MSWindows network?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, backup, windows

Is it possible to use a Linux machine to backup everything on a Windows network?

I would like to backup MS databases and also drives, so if a database record needs restoring, it can be done easily, and if a drive gets corrupted, it can be re-imaged easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might get what you want from [Amanda](http://www.amanda.org/) (Advanced Maryland Automatic Network Disk Archiver), which was developed to backup an entire university campus.  It also has a windows client.

Note this is quite a mature piece of software.  IIRC it's been around since sometime in the 1980s or 1990s and is still under active development.

For databases, you will still have to do DB backups and back up the files with Amanda.  I don't believe it will directly interface with the DBMS software.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before using a very quick and ugly shell script, you just have to share the folder where you want stuff backed up. On a nightly basis I tar'd and gzip'd the files and then moved them off to a larger mounted file store.

Things to note.

1) Make sure you test your a random backup regularly
2) Make sure your temporary store has lots of disk space
3) Make sure your computer is connected to a UPS.

Comment: I think my biggest concern is not to slow down the whole network when backing up 50Tb.  Is there a linux command to slow down the copy.  So instead of copying a file and 100% full speed, copy it at 10% the normal speed?

Comment: I couldn't think of a way to do it with cp but there is with a command called valve. http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/valve/